# Cant bind to ___ since it isnt a known native property

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to use `*ngFor` to render a list of components:

```
<componentx
    *ngFor="let a of data"
    [viewName]="a.name"
    [viewQuery]="a.prop2"
    [viewValues]="a.prop3"></componentx>

// ...
export class App {
    public data:any[];
    constructor() { this.data = [{name: 'foo', prop2: 'bar', prop3: 'hello'}]}
```

}

This is the component itself:

```
export class ComponentX {
    @Input() viewName:string;
    @Input() viewQuery:string;
    @Input() viewValues:any[]; 
}
```

When I run this code I get the following error:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'viewName' since it isn't a known native property ("
     <componentx
        *ngFor="let a of data"
        [ERROR ->][viewName]="a.name"
        [viewQuery]="a.prop2"
        [viewValues]="a.prop3"></componentx>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error generally means:

1- That specific @Input doesn't exits in your component , which in your case it does.

2- You've forgotten to declare your component in the root app module.

```
import {ComponentX} from 'its/path';

@NgModule({ 
    declarations:[ComponentX]
}) 
export class AppModule { 
}
```

Comment: Nice. i managed to solve the problem by including  `ComponentX` in the `directives` field of the AppComponent declaration.

Comment: @dopatraman , so you're using the old Angular2, because in the new versions directives doesn't exits anymore , what version are you on ?

Comment: @dopatraman Your edit has rendered this answer incorrect for the released version of Angular 2. For it to be useful to others; I think it should be rolled back. If you really want to add the code that worked for you, it should be an addendum with a version clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that you did import your component -'ComponentX' in class 'App'

Comment: how do i do this?

Comment: import { ComponentX } from './ComponentX.component'; Used the path of your ComponentX, this is just an example

Comment: Add import { ComponentX } from './ComponentX.component';  at the top of class 'App'. Used the path of your ComponentX, this is just an example

Comment: do i have to include it in the AppComponent declaration somehow?

Comment: If possible for you, please post the entire code or provide link to plunker.